# Using values in one dataframe as arguments for model estimated on another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to estimate models in one dataframe, but the formula for each model has some "moving parts" which come from another dataframe. For example, say I wish to estimate the following model (I can't post picture and found no way to type latex equations):
mpg = a + b*log(w_1 * drat + w_2 * hp)

where w_1 and w_2 are weights, which for example are either 0.5 or 1. I use expand.grid() to create a dataframe of weights, then mutate() a formula using paste() or paste0() with the variable names and the value of the weights, and then pass it to the lm() function.

However, the model estimated is just using the formula found in the first row of the weights dataframe. This is solved if I use group_by() before estimating the models.

The question is - why? why doesn't the first code work? what does group_by() achieve here that makes it possible?

```r
library(tidyverse)
cars <- mtcars

w <- seq(from=0.5, to=1, by=0.5)
weights <- as_tibble(expand.grid(w1=w,w2=w))


#Doesn't work - the lm model is fit using the formula from the first row only
weights %>%
  mutate(formula_weights = paste0("mpg~log(",w1,"*drat+",w2,"*hp)")) %>%
  mutate(r2 = summary(lm(data=cars, formula = formula_weights))$r.squared)

#Does work - model is fit using the w1 and w2 values from each row (formula_weights)
weights %>%
  mutate(formula_weights = paste0("mpg~log(",w1,"*drat+",w2,"*hp)")) %>%
  group_by(formula_weights) %>%
  mutate(r2 = summary(lm(data=cars, formula = formula_weights))$r.squared)
```

The output without group_by():

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     w1    w2 formula_weights             r2
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl>
1   0.5   0.5 mpg~log(0.5*drat+0.5*hp) 0.715
2   1     0.5 mpg~log(1*drat+0.5*hp)   0.715
3   0.5   1   mpg~log(0.5*drat+1*hp)   0.715
4   1     1   mpg~log(1*drat+1*hp)     0.715
```

The output with group_by():

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   formula_weights [4]
     w1    w2 formula_weights             r2
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl>
1   0.5   0.5 mpg~log(0.5*drat+0.5*hp) 0.715
2   1     0.5 mpg~log(1*drat+0.5*hp)   0.709
3   0.5   1   mpg~log(0.5*drat+1*hp)   0.718
4   1     1   mpg~log(1*drat+1*hp)     0.715
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
weights %>%
  mutate(formula_weights = paste0("mpg~log(",w1,"*drat+",w2,"*hp)")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(r2 = summary(lm(data=cars, formula = formula_weights))$r.squared)
#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 4 x 4
#     w1    w2 formula_weights             r2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl>
#1   0.5   0.5 mpg~log(0.5*drat+0.5*hp) 0.715
#2   1     0.5 mpg~log(1*drat+0.5*hp)   0.709
#3   0.5   1   mpg~log(0.5*drat+1*hp)   0.718
#4   1     1   mpg~log(1*drat+1*hp)     0.715
```

---

Or use `map`

```
library(purrr)
weights %>%
     mutate(r2 = map_dbl(paste0("mpg~log(",w1,"*drat+",w2,"*hp)"), ~ 
                    summary(lm(data = cars, formula =  .x))$r.squared))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#     w1    w2    r2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   0.5   0.5 0.715
#2   1     0.5 0.709
#3   0.5   1   0.718
#4   1     1   0.715
```

Comment: When I tried to solve my original problem, I saw that rowwise() and group_by() give the same solution. I still don't really understand why. when I mutate formula_weights for example - dplyr "knows" that this is rowwise. So why does using lm with formula=formula_weights requires that I explicitly tell it to it rowwise()?

Comment: @ArielKarlinsky This has to do with how mutate works. Typically it is works on vectors (e.g. columns). so it expects to use vectors (other columns) as inputs, and apply functions that are vectorized (e.g. working element by element) and return vectors of the same length.
rowwise and group_by split this computation into groups so that in each group the computation is performed independently. within each group, you are still expected to work in a vectorized way - but if the group is of size 1 (e.g. as in rowwise) then it doesn't really matter. compare with the base function ave()

Answer (score 0):

use sapply inside your mutate. summary/lm are not vectorized

```
weights %>%
mutate(formula_weights = paste0("mpg~log(",w1,"*drat+",w2,"*hp)")) %>%
mutate(r2 = sapply(formula_weights,
                   function(fw) summary(lm(data=cars, formula =))$r.squared))
```

Comment: `sapply` is like using `map` (looping).